# Accessing YouTube live streams with Web Audio API

Tags: google-plus, html5-audio, youtube-javascript-api, web-audio-api

Is it possible to access YouTube live stream content (video/audio) in Javascript and Web Audio API e.g. for real-time mixing of the audio content?

Is the payload HTML5 compatible or is it Flash only?

... or is access to these streams limited via CORS or licensing clauses?

In my case, live streams would be created in Google Hangout http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/hangouts/onair.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only access the content for HTML5 streams, and of course I'd expect this would not be available in the future for encrypted streams.  Hangouts use a plugin right now, so you can't do this.